# Hook for Image Transforms

Tags: plugin-development, image-transforms, events, hook

I'm interested in creating a plug-in that creates a new type of transform. Is there a hook/event related to image transforms?

Comment: Hey Brett, I’m pretty sure this Q&A will answer your question: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/is-it-possible-to-override-thumbnail-generation