# Dynamically generating a JPG from SVG

Tags: image-transforms

I'm wondering how I can dynamically generate a JPG fallback image from an SVG. Can image transforms be modified to handle this?

Comment: I don't believe so, because technically speaking SVG's aren't 'images' in the true sense of the word. A reasonable workaround would be to add a 'JPG fallback' asset field to your assets, so when an SVG is uploaded you can select the file you want to fallback to from there.

Comment: @JamieWade Unfortunately that solution won't work in my case. Based on a little more research ImageMagick is able to do the operation server side, but that isn't the library Craft uses. I wonder if there is a way for Craft to plug into a different image processor?

Answer (score 4):

No, Craft will not be able to generate JPGs from SVGs out of the box (I tested it), but it should be relatively easy to write a plugin handling it.

As GD doesn't support SVG, ImageMagick support is a must. Craft actually *does* use ImageMagick, if its installed on your server – so your first step would be to check for ImageMagick support. An easy way to do that, is to use Craft's [ImagesService](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/ImagesService#isImagick-detail).

From there, the actual PHP code generating the JPG should be relatively straight-forward – check [this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289686/rendering-an-svg-file-to-a-png-or-jpeg-in-php) for a concise example (not tested the mentioned code myself).

Note: Be advised that Craft actually implements all of its image manipulation through the [Imagine](https://imagine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) library – I'm pretty sure Imagine would handle the generation, but if you need to work with ImageMagick directly you could do

```
$factory = new \Imagine\Imagick\Imagine();
$svg = $factory->open( $path );
$imagick = $svg->getImagick();
```

Finally, when it comes to implementing the JPG generation you have a few options – for example you could [create a Twig filter](https://cameronspear.com/blog/craft-cms-twig-filter-extension/):

```
<img src="{{ image | svgFallback }}" />
```

You could also implement it as a [template variable method](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/variables):

```
<img src="{{ craft.yourPluginName.getSvgFallback( image ) }}" />
```

...or you could even hook into [AssetsService events](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/AssetsService#events) if you needed to generate the fallback automatically.

Updated answer: The original question asks if "image transforms can be modified to handle this". The short answer is no – ideally there would be a `beforeTransformApplied` hook or something like that, but as of 2.3 there isn't (see [this thread](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/is-it-possible-to-hook-into-image-transforms) for reference). My opinion is that your best bet is creating a variable method or Twig filter, as outlined above.